# How to Manage SQL Buffer in case of SQL Express

Tags: sql-server, appdomainsetup

I am using sql express having 5-6 database and considerable more users. Over a period of time users experiencing slowness due to buffer is full.
 Or another issue CLR- AppDomain is getting download due to that service are getting aborted.

What is the best way to manage the buffer if have multiple database in a same SQL server express?

Comment: Assuming your system has memory that Express currently can't use because of the 1GB limitation, you could create a SQL Express instance for each database, then at least they'd each get their own 1GB. But if your databases are 10GB that may not help much.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Hi, I am only a traveler from the review queue. Is this question Ok ? For me it was either unclear as we were missing a lot information from hardware to licencing. Or eligible to a simple Tb close with advice about posting serveur question on server fault.

Comment: @DragandDrop I think it's fine here.

Comment: [Duplicate posting](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8646c770-0cab-4963-9174-11fa8e6ddc26/how-to-manage-sql-buffer-in-case-of-sql-express?forum=sqlexpress) in msdn.